# Supabase server-side auth with Supabase

Tags: authentication, server-side, supabase, qwik

Is there anyone who was able to successfully implement Supabase authentication in Qwik? Client-side is quite straight forward, but server-side is not.

I have followed various examples, all without success.

For server-side authentication to work you need to store access token and refresh token in a cookie for the server to be able to retrieve it to set the supabase session. However you only have access to cookies from within a routeloader or onRequest event. Neither have my preference for this means for every request you will be re-creating the supabase client and I think a singleton would be better/more efficient.

I also tried auth-helper for qwik but this comes down to the same thing. It stores the tokens in a cookie for you but still via a routeLoader or onRequest event.

I am struggling with this for a few weeks now and any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

-Gerard